# Getting Variable from sqlplus

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I am trying to get a value from sqlplus like below. However, it does not echo what I want. Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
OLDEST_PARTITION='sqlplus / as sysdba << EOF
select PARTITION_NAME 
from dba_tab_partitions 
where table_name='AUD$' and PARTITION_NAME not like '%FIRST%' and rownum<2
order by PARTITION_NAME asc;
EOF'
echo $OLDEST_PARTITION
```

And the result is this:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba << EOF select PARTITION_NAME from dba_tab_partitions where table_name=AUD and PARTITION_NAME not like %FIRST% and rownum<2 order by PARTITION_NAME asc; EOF
```

Comment: The first and last single-quote should be a backquote `\``

Answer (score 1):

As [meuh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299545/getting-variable-from-sqlplus#comment527352_299545) pointed out, unless you copy/pasted the script incorrectly, you have single-quote marks where you need to have backticks. Changing them makes the script into:

```
#!/bin/ksh
OLDEST_PARTITION=`sqlplus / as sysdba << EOF
select PARTITION_NAME 
from dba_tab_partitions 
where table_name='AUD$' and PARTITION_NAME not like '%FIRST%' and rownum<2
order by PARTITION_NAME asc;
EOF
`
echo "$OLDEST_PARTITION"
```

I took care to keep the `EOF` on its own line, and also quote the OLDEST_PARTITION variable.