# How to assign select statement from Oracle to shell variable

Tags: shell-script, oracle-database

I have a script which is working fine in `TOAD`:

```
SELECT max (ID)+1 from apps_details;
```

When I'm trying to run it in the shell script, I'm getting an error:

```
DB_CONNECT="XXXXX/XXXXX@XXXXXX"

echo "Inserting the DataBase"
/oravl01/oracle/12.1.0.1/bin/sqlplus -s $DB_CONNECT <<END
set head off
set feedback off
set pagesize 2400
set linesize 2048

ID_VAL=`SELECT max (ID)+1 from apps_details;`
exit
END
```

```
/pciuser/tools/jenkins/jenkins/scripts/Jenkins_Internal/Create_Jenkins_Container/InsertToDB.ksh[31]: syntax error at line 1: `(' unexpected
```

**Line 31** refers to `oravl01` line, but I know the issue is not there, as once I'm removing the `ID_VAL` assignment, it works.

what is the correct syntax to write it?

Comment: Looks like you need something along the lines of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/299545/117549

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/347378/117549

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Is the `ID_VAL` a shell variable or something in the SQL? And the `set` commands? Are those the shell builtin `set` or some sort of SQL thing?

Comment: @terdon ID_VAL is a shell variable, which I later want to use for an INSERT SQL statement. the set command also belongs to the SQL.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking about, arielma. Do you mean indenting the lines between the <<END and END?  EOF is "End of File", so it doesn't make sense in the context of alignment.  If it helps clarify your question, please [edit your question using this "edit" link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/535572/edit) and while you're at it, put your "ID_VAL is a shell variable..." update into the question, too. Thank you!

Comment: @arielma so you need to run the 4 `set` commands in SQL, and then run the SELECT statement and save the output of the SELECT statement in the _shell_ variable `ID_VAL`, is that right?

Comment: @terdon yes, and then use ID_VAL in other insert statement

Comment: Right. Then my (now edited and udeleted) answer should work for you.

Comment: @JeffSchaller your answers helped me to get also to this thread which eventually solved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426207/assign-output-of-an-oracle-sql-query-to-a-variable-in-shell-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is much cleaner (and simpler) to first define your command and then run it to save its output:

```
DB_CONNECT="XXXXX/XXXXX@XXXXXX"

read -r -d '' command <<END
set head off
set feedback off
set pagesize 2400
set linesize 2048
SELECT max (ID)+1 from apps_details;
exit
END

echo "Inserting the DataBase"
ID_VAL=$(/oravl01/oracle/12.1.0.1/bin/sqlplus -s "$DB_CONNECT" <<<"$command")
```

That way, you can easily store the output in a variable and you have the command separate from the flow of the script which will make it easier both to understand and to maintain in future.

Comment: It was close, but eventually, other command worked for me. posting the answer

Comment: @arielma does a simple command like `var=$(/oravl01/oracle/12.1.0.1/bin/sqlplus -s "$DB_CONNECT" "select 1 from apps_details")` work? I don't know `sqlplus` at all. The `mysql` command needs an `-e` when you run a command from the terminal, are you sure the format is right? And do you need the `set` stuff? Why, if you're not looking at an actual table but only want the results? Does removing those help?

Comment: @terdon At least in my environment `sqlplus ... "$command"` fails, while `sqlplus ... <<<"$command"` works. I.e. it won't accept a script passed to it as an argument (string), but it will be happy to read it from standard input.

Comment: @fra-san ah! That makes sense, I should have realized from the command int he question! Thanks.

Comment: @arielma see updated answer.

Comment: @arielma if you have a new question, please post it separately. It's very hard to do this in the comments. However, I'm willing to bet your problem is that you aren't quoting your variables.

Comment: @terdon Just a short question as I'm not sure yet it requires a new thread. In toad, I'm getting the answer 548 (the column is Number), however here the result with 11 chars (548 and 8 spcaes). any idea why?

Comment: @arielma sorry, but this site is strictly questions and answers. Comments should only be used to ask for clarification (which is why they're harder to format and have a character limit). You can use [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) if you want to have a discussion. Anyway, as I said before, my idea is that you aren't quoting your variables but I can't tell from what you're saying. Another possibility is that the `set` commands you're using are changing the size of what is returned, but I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

These commands worked for me:

```
DB_CONNECT="XXXXX/XXXXX@XXXXX"

ID_VAL=$(sqlplus -s $DB_CONNECT <<END
set head off
set feedback off
set pagesize 2400
set linesize 2048
SELECT max (ID)+1 from apps_details;
exit;
END
)

echo $ID_VAL
```

Comment: Great! Glad you solved it and thank you for taking the time to post your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some alternatives, along the lines of [terdon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/535574/315749), that try to make it easier to handle SQL*Plus' output given that [you are trying](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/535572/how-to-assign-select-statement-from-oracle-to-shell-variable#comment992627_535572) to fetch it into the shell variable `ID_VAL`.

By default, SQL statements executed in SQL*Plus produce formatted reports, made of columns whose width will depend on the respective data types. This will lead to some possibly unwanted effects: for instance, the left-padded numbers you pointed out [in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/535572/how-to-assign-select-statement-from-oracle-to-shell-variable#comment992706_535574).

Demonstration:

```
$ DB_CONNECT="user/password@db"
$ ID_VAL="$(sqlplus -s $DB_CONNECT <<'END'
set feedback off
set head off
set pagesize 0
SELECT 123 FROM DUAL
/
END
)"
$ printf '"%s"\n' "$ID_VAL"
"       123"
$ printf '%s' "$ID_VAL" | od -An -tx1
 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 31 32 33
```

Some alternatives:

1. If you are selecting a number, convert it to a string and trim it in your SQL statement. With everything else in the above script unchanged (I'll keep using my dummy `SELECT` statement, for ease of testing):

   ```sql
   SELECT TRIM(TO_CHAR(123)) FROM DUAL;
   ```
2. Use `dbms_output.put_line` in a PL/SQL block:

   ```
   ID_VAL="$(sqlplus -s $DB_CONNECT <<'END'
   set serveroutput on
   set feedback off
   DECLARE
   myvar NUMBER;
   BEGIN
   SELECT 123 INTO myvar FROM DUAL;
   dbms_output.put_line(myvar);
   END;
   /
   END
   )"
   ```

   Note that `set serveroutput on` is required, no output is shown otherwise.

With both (1) and (2) you will get:

```
$ printf '"%s"\n' "$ID_VAL"
"123"
$ printf '%s' "$ID_VAL" | od -An -tx1
 31 32 33
```

Note, however, that these approaches will fail if you are selecting a string with flanking blank characters you want to preserve (e.g.   `foo`  ). You may enclose that string in quotes and remove them afterwards, or:

3. Let SQL*Plus format its output as CSV:

   ```
   ID_VAL="$(sqlplus -s -M "CSV ON" $DB_CONNECT <<'END'
   set feedback off
   set head off
   SELECT '  foo  ' FROM DUAL;
   END
   )"
   printf '"%s"\n' "$ID_VAL"
   ""  foo  ""
   ```

   Unlike numbers, strings will be double-quoted, requiring a bit of post-processing. Assuming that the returned value does not contain `<newline>` characters, one way could be to use `sed` to remove the starting and the ending `"` characters (everything else unchanged):

   ```
   ID_VAL="$(sqlplus -s -M "CSV ON" $DB_CONNECT <<'END' | sed 's/^"//; s/"$//;'
   ```

The best option will depend on your actual use case.